# Is tuple timeout configuration per spout?

Tags: apache-storm

Topologies have `a tuple timeout` setting. If I set this as 30s and have the below topology:

If a tuple emitted by `spoutA` takes 20s to be emitted to Kafka `topicA`, and then `spoutB` takes 20s to emit and ack - will `spoutA` consider this 40s and timeout and retry? or will nothing be retried because each spout only took 20s?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When spout `B` read message from topic `A` storm will consider it as completly new message. So averege complete latency will be 20 seconds not 40.